# Split a record into two records based on some condition in mysql

Tags: mysql

I work on cleaning data which has normal shifts and night shifts data. Table has site enter time,site exit time,room enter time,room exit time etc fields which is used in calculating presence time and work time etc kpis. In case of normal shift i show employee journey in a single record as provided in mysl table.

Site name,employee,site enter time,task,site exit time

In case of night shift i want to split a record into two records.For eg- An employee entered in site on 06-02-2019 21:00:00 and he left site at 07-02-2019 04:00:00. In first record ,i want to show site enter time -  06-02-2019 21:00:00 , site exit time - 06-02-2019 11:59:59
In second record , site enter time will be -  07-02-2019 12:00:00 and site exit will be - 07-02-2019 04:00:00

```
    create table smartview.test_table1(
Employee varchar(45),
site_name varchar(45),
Employee_code varchar(45),
Room_no varchar(45),
Task_type varchar(45),
Site_Enter_Time timestamp,
Room_Enter_Time timestamp,
Room_Exit_Time timestamp,
Site_Exit_Time timestamp
);


insert into smartview.test_table1(Employee,site_name,Employee_code,Room_no,Task_type,Site_Enter_Time,Room_Enter_Time,Room_Exit_Time,Site_Exit_Time) values
('Sharma','test_site1','003','Room2','floor cleaning',STR_TO_DATE('02-03-2019 14:00:00','%m-%d-%Y %H:%i:%s'),STR_TO_DATE('02-03-2019 16:00:00','%m-%d-%Y %H:%i:%s'),STR_TO_DATE('02-03-2019 23:00:00','%m-%d-%Y %H:%i:%s'),STR_TO_DATE('02-04-2019 02:00:00','%m-%d-%Y %H:%i:%s'));
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.  Please delete the insert statement, and instead include sample input and output _table_ data, with the data appearing as a formatted table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UNION` to create two rows where enter and exit times are spread across different days. Simplified query:

```
-- shift ends on same day
SELECT employee, site_enter_time, site_exit_time
FROM test_table1
WHERE DATE(site_enter_time) = DATE(site_exit_time)

UNION ALL
-- shift ends on next day: first record
SELECT employee, site_enter_time, DATE(site_exit_time) - INTERVAL 1 SECOND
FROM test_table1
WHERE DATE(site_enter_time) = DATE(site_exit_time) - INTERVAL 1 DAY

UNION ALL
-- shift ends on next day: second record
SELECT employee, DATE(site_exit_time), site_exit_time
FROM test_table1
WHERE DATE(site_enter_time) = DATE(site_exit_time) - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```